# Changing CSS Selector for hyperlink

Tags: css

I want to change CSS selector for hyperlink using Style tag in my code but not sure how to do it.

I know i can use an external CSS with syntax like

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}
```

However i want to use this within style attribute of a span element like

```
<span class="Button1a" style="padding: 15px 20px; a:color: #fff;">
<span class="Button1a" style="padding: 15px 20px; a.color: #fff;">
<span class="Button1a" style="padding: 15px 20px; a>color: #fff;">
<span class="Button1a" style="padding: 15px 20px; color: #fff;">
```

None of the above seem to be working for me.

Comment: Is there a practical reason for wanting to style your links this way?  Using inline styles is a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: the inline style syntax is muy malo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs of all element `style` is for that element only, and there is no way you could alter children style this way.

Only the inherited values are changed

Only solution for your specific problem:

```
<span id="parent">
    <a href="#" style="color: #000">Link</a>
</span>
```

Comment: this hint gave me what i was looking for. Added styling to the child and it got solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are using selector inside withing `style` attribute which is not correct.

```
style="padding: 15px 20px; a:color: #fff;">
                           ^
```

use it like this

```
<span class="Button1a" style="padding: 15px 20px; color: #fff;">
```

Comment: well that was the first thing i tried. forgot to include that. Had to add color to the child of span. And it worked.

Comment: (S)he wants to have an `a` tag inside a `span` and modify the `a` via the `span` I think.

Answer (score 1):

That selector matches `<a>` tags, but you have `<span>` elements. Either way, your `style` attribute needs to contain only the contents of a selector block:

```
<span class="Button1a" style="padding: 15px 20px; color: #fff;">
```

I wouldn't recommend placing properties inside of the `style` attribute. It doesn't scale well and is hard to maintain. Use a stylesheet instead:

```
.Button1a {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: i don't want to use stylesheets. The behavior i want is for specific elements and sheets have general behavior for all elements.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: You can target specific elements with ID selectors. Using inline styles will make your code unmaintainable in the long run.

Comment: Well i will follow up your advise in my next designing, but i am sure in my current scenario implementing everything in external sheets won't be as easy. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution, since it can't be done directly.
You must have `color: inherit;` attached to the `a` tag you want to modify in some form of CSS. Having that included, you can modify it's color by using:

```
<span style="color: #fff;">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</span>
```